# make toolbar rtl in pre 17 api devices

Tags: android, material-design, android-toolbar, right-to-left

I want to use material design in pre 17 api devices and I need rtl version of it. i use [RTL-Toolbar-Android-AppCompat](https://github.com/arashsammak/RTL-Toolbar-Android-AppCompat) and [Toolbar](https://github.com/alirezaafkar/Toolbar) library but non of them can help me. each lib has a problem . any body can help me?

Comment: Have you found anything for this yet !?